# How do I get the update frequency of the accelerometer in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, accelerometer

I am currently working with the flutter_sensors package to get the acceleration data.

How do I get or measure the update frequency of the accelerometer?

As far as I know the flutter_sensors and the sensors package doesn't provide a way of getting the frequency. Is there a better package?

I know that I can set the frequency with the flutter_sensors package but I can't trust that the data always comes at the right time or can I?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I choose to use the Stopwatch of the dart:core (https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/Stopwatch-class.html).

Every time I get new acceleration data I store the Stopwatch.elapsedMilliseconds.
With this data I can calculate the frequency.

Answer (score 0):

Grab a second (or 10 seconds) of data, and see how many distinct values you get.

You can use debounce in https://pub.dev/packages/stream_transform to automatically eliminate adjacent equal values.